# Mid-late 60s anthology: empaths working for the police, and workers in space suits greeting each other with "Hello gentle human"

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

I was a kid and read a monthly (?) anthology. One short story that stuck with me was about a group of empaths who worked for the police to help with crowds at concerts and stuff.

And about the same time (same story? I was a kid) there was another short story where the greeting was “Hello, gentle human.”  Everyone worked in space suits so gender was not clear until the station and same sex was not a problem.

Comment: Hi Bianca. That's a nice start you've got here; if you can, please take a look at [these guidelines on story-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in. Really, anything, however minor, might be useful :) cheers!

Comment: For example, what year were you a “kid?” This would be an example of a helpful detail, though minute (Thanks, @Jenayah).

Comment: The first one could be one of Anne McCaffrey's short stories from the *To Ride Pegasus* collection, possibly *A Bridle for Pegasus*.  The second one doesn't sound familiar to me.

Comment: The second one sounds like Andre Norton to me. Her characters tended to address men formally as "gentle homo" and women as "gentle fem". I can imagine that becoming "gentle human" in a situation where gender wasn't clear. Sorry, I can't suggest a specific work, Norton wrote a shed-load of scifi in the 60s. She was also into various levels of telepathy, which might fit the empaths in the first story, but then so were a lot of sci-fi authors around then.

Comment: Thanks, Jenayah! So it would have been mid to late 60s or early 70s. this was in an anthology.  There is a group of crowd control empaths/police officers at a large venue for a concert. They spread out and yet stay in range of each other. There were at least three and one was a female. I may have merged the gentle human thingy had people on a space station I think so no one knew the gender of the other due to the space suit. Pax